# TSQL Cursor Alternative to Speed up my query

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

```
 Row Status  Time
 1   Status1 1383264075
 2   Status1 1383264195
 3   Status1 1383264315
 4   Status2 1383264435
 5   Status2 1383264555
 6   Status2 1383264675
 7   Status2 1383264795
 8   Status1 1383264915
 9   Status3 1383265035
 10  Status3 1383265155
 11  Status2 1383265275
 12  Status3 1383265395
 13  Status1 1383265515
 14  Status1 1383265535
 15  Status2 1383265615
```

The `[Time]` column holds POSIX time

I want to be able to calculate the number of seconds a given `[Status]` is active for within a given time period without using CURSORS.  If this is the only then that is fine as I've already done that.

Using the above sample data extract, how do I calculate how long "Status1" has been active for?

That is, Substract `Row1.[Time]` from `Row4.[Time]`, Substract `Row8.[Time]` from `Row9.[Time]`, Substract `Row13.[Time]` from `Row15.[Time]`.

Thankyou in advance

Comment: Could you tell us what the desired results would be from this set of 15 rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [solution by @erikxiv](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21539491/297408) will work if the `Row` values have no gaps. If they do have gaps, you could try the [following method](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/17072/2):

```
SELECT
  TotalDuration = SUM(next.Time - curr.Time)
FROM
  dbo.atable AS curr
CROSS APPLY
  (
    SELECT TOP (1) Time
    FROM dbo.atable
    WHERE Row > curr.Row
    ORDER BY Row ASC
  ) AS next
WHERE
  curr.Status = 'Status1'
;
```

For every row matching the specified status, the correlated subquery in the CROSS APPLY clause will fetch the next `Time` value based on the ascending order of `Row`. The current row's time is then subtracted from the next row's time and all the differences are added up using `SUM()`.

Please note that in both solutions it is implied that the order of `Row` values follows the order of `Time` values. In other words, `ORDER BY Row` is assumed to be equivalent to `ORDER BY Time` or, if `Time` can have duplicates, to `ORDER BY Time, Row`.

Comment: Thanks Andriy M, there are gaps in the "Row" values so your works better

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that each row represents that the specific `Status` is active from the specified `Time` until the next row, one would have to somehow calculate the difference between row N and N+1. One way would be to use a nested query (try it here: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9137b/10)).

```
SELECT SUM(Duration) as Duration
FROM (
  SELECT f.Status, s.Time-f.Time as Duration
  FROM Table1 f
  JOIN Table1 s on s.Row = f.Row+1
  WHERE f.Status = 'Status1') a
```

Comment: You could actually avoid using a subselect. `SELECT SUM(s.Time - f.Time) FROM ...` would work just fine.